# Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Scale.ConcurrencyManager' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host

Tags: c#, kubernetes, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-aks

The application is in Azure Functions,

The error that we are getting from container Pod logs is "Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Scale.ConcurrencyManager' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.26.0".

In our application version all of the dll ver is 3.0.30.0

[image]

In the "dll" folder of debug is having the version with 3.0.30.0

[image]

And in this version 3.0.30.0, it has the class "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Scale.ConcurrencyManager"

[image]

Not sure, where this "assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.26.0" is coming from.

Answer (score 5):

For me this was happening because **Azure Functions Core Tools** version mismatched due to upgradation of **Visual Studio** to latest version.
Removing the Azure Function Tools from the system path `C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools` and Let Visual Studio automatically install **Azure Functions Core Tools** fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as below log.

> Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Scale.ConcurrencyManager' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.25.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

It was due to my base image for azure functions was old. using the newer base image with below tag(`mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:3.4.2`) has fixed my issue.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:3.4.2 AS base
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1.416 AS build
WORKDIR /src
```

Comment: Can you please re phrase your answer and be more specific about the keywords like - base image for azure functions. Additionally help with these commands

Comment: @CodeConstruct, above example shows a Dockerfile for running an Azure function in a container. base image and all the terms are specific to dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got to know that after some drill down.

Answer (score 0):

This is not direct answer to your question but a tool that would answer it for you. As I had a lot of this kind of errors I have written a helper  code to do just that. Its written for the .net framework but with minor changes you can have same thing on core.

```
       //folder where dependencies should be found
       var dir = @"C:\Repos\Project\bin"; 
       //dll or exe that you want to inspect
        var dll = @"C:\Repos\Project\bin\Project.dll"; 
        var asm = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(dll);

        var stack = new Stack<Data>();
        stack.Push(new Data { 
           ReferencesPath = Array.Empty<Assembly>(), 
           Assembly = asm
        });
        List<AssemblyName> visited = new List<AssemblyName>();


        while (stack.Any())
        {
            var current = stack.Pop();
            var dependencies = current.Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();
            visited.Add(current.Assembly.GetName());
            foreach (var item in dependencies)
            {
                if (!visited.Any(x => x.FullName == item.FullName))
                {
                    Assembly dependency;
                    try
                    {
                        dependency = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(item.FullName);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        var path = Path.Combine(dir, item.Name) + ".dll";
                        dependency = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(path);
                    }

                    if (dependency.GetName().Version != item.Version)
                    {
                        ; // put breakpoint here and inspect dependency 
   // and item when you find your dll in wrong version 
   // you can inspect current.ReferencesPath to see dependencies 
   // chain that causes the error
                    }

                    stack.Push(new Data
                    {
                        Assembly = dependency,
                        ReferencesPath = current.ReferencesPath.Concat(
new[] { current.Assembly }).ToArray()
                    });
                }
            }
        }



class Data
{
    public Assembly[] ReferencesPath { get; set; }
    public Assembly Assembly { get; internal set; }
}
```